# Hibernate sets map-key to null during 'update'

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm

Imagine you have

```
@EqualsAndHashcode(of = "id")
class AnAggregate {

    private int id;
    private Map<String, AValueObject> childrenByValueA;

    void replaceChild(AValueObject childToReplace) {
        childrenByValueA.put(childToReplace.getValueA(), childToReplace);
    }

}
```

AValueObject should be a VO, but because of the nature of relational DB, it has a dummy ID:

```
@EqualsAndHashcode(exclude = "aDummyID")
class AValueObject {
    private int aDummyID;
    private String valueA;
    private String valueB;

}
```

now, take a look at the part of xml mapping for AnAggregate class:

```
<map name="childrenByValueA" fetch="select" batch-size="666">
            <key column="aggregate_id"/>
            <map-key type="string" column="value_a"/>
            <one-to-many class="AValueObject"/>
</map>
```

Now, when I create tables as follows:

```
create table an_aggregate (
    aggregate_id bigint,
    primary key (metric_id)
);

crate table a_value_object (
    vo_id bigint,
    aggregate_id bigint,
    value_a varchar(255),
    value_b varchar(255),
    primary_key (vo_id);
);

alter table a_value_object add constraint a_fk foreign key (aggregate_id) references an_aggregate;
```

everything seems to work.

But if I declare:

```
value_a varchar(255) **not null**
```

then I have an integrity violation during the update operation.

Let's assume we have **anAggregate - (1)**
and **aValueObject (1, 1, value_a, value_b)**
and we want to replace that row with **(_, 1, modified_value_a, modified_value_b)**

It turns out, that hibernate tries to do stuff in the following order:

- insert into a_value_object values (2, 1, modified_value_a,
  modified_value_b)
- update a_value_object set aggregate_id=null, value_a=null, where aggregate_id=1 and vo_id=1
- delete from a_value_object where vo_id=1

**and fail during the second step, because it violates the 'not null' constraint on 'value_a'.**

**Question(s):**
How to overcome this? Why is hibernate executing stuff in such a strange order? Why does it try to null-out fields it shouldn't?

Comment: The order in which Hibernate does "stuff" is an internal implementation, and should be your concern.  Only the integrity of the database and whatever contracts exist should matter.

Comment: And hibernate violates that contract by setting NULL to a value that is not nullable. My question is, how to fix it without sacrificing that 'not null' clause.

Comment: Did Hibernate assign `NULL`, or was that value already null?

Comment: As I written, it tries to assign NULL during that 'replacement' operation